# What character set does encode the "é" character as 130 in decimal?

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc, character-encoding

I'm doing an example Java application that uses JDBC to extract some data from MySQL. It works bad with the characters á, é, í, ó and ú, when these caracters are in the database my application shows strange characters such "," or "?". For example, if in the database there is the é character, when my application extracts it through jdbc as a byte, I get the byte 130. I have tried to find what character set is using my application when extracting data from my database.

I have not found any character set which encodes the "é" with the 130 number in decimal. ¿Can you help me to find it? I only need the character set name.

Comment: [ASCII Extended Character Sets, PC](http://academic.evergreen.edu/projects/biophysics/technotes/program/ascii_ext-pc.htm)

Comment: @dasblinkenlight: That doesn't really give an encoding name though. "Extended ASCII" is a horrible name for an ill-defined *collection* of encodings.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suspect you're looking for [IBM code page 437](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_page_437). (There may well be others that encode the same character in the same way, of course.) Whether a particular Java implementation knows about it or not is very implementation-specific though... on the machine I'm looking at, I believe it's available as charset "IBM437", but YMMV.

If you have control over the database, it would be best to ensure that all the data is stored with more portable encodings (e.g. UTF-8 or UTF-16). Note that you should be able to determine the current encoding by looking at the database schema.

Comment: Codepage 850 is also an option

Comment: Jon Skeet, you are right. I got a string from the database as an array of bytes, decoded it through IBM-437 and now I see properly all á, é, í, ó and ú characters in my application. But there is a thing I do not understand. I saw that my MySQL database uses latin1 as character set. Why have I to decode strings from my database using IBM-437 if my database is really using latin1? It is not logical.

Comment: @user3289695: I suspect that whatever *created* the content was using IBM-437 but claiming it was ISO-Latin-1. It's unfortunate that often if a system is broken in the same way when both reading and writing, that error can stay hidden for a very long time. It means you need to be careful though - you may find that some *other* tools have been writing the data genuinely using Latin-1, in which case decoding it with IBM-437 will be a bad idea :(